# keep selected values in select box field after search

Tags: php, jquery

I want to keep the selected values in select box after search .This is a vehicle search filter page and Page is coded using php and connected with database.

> Database have 2 columns for both options that is driver age for 21-24 and driver_age for 25+ as some vehicles also available for both age of drivers

code below

```
<script>
$('#driver').change(function() {
  if($('#driver option:selected').val() == '21-24') {
    $('#driver').attr('name','driverage');
  }

  if($('#driver option:selected').val() == '25+') {
    $('#driver').attr('name','driver_age'); 
  }
});
</script>

<form id="myform" method="GET" action="">
  <div class="fields">
    <p>Vehicle Type</p>
    <select class="car" name="car_type" id="car_type">
      <option value="0">Select Vehicle</option>
      <?php if(count($vehicleType) > 0 ){
        foreach($vehicleType as $vt){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $vt ?>" <?=isset($_GET['car_type'])&&$_GET['car_type']==$vt?'selected':'';?> ><?php echo $vt ?></option>
          <?php }

      } ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="fields">
    <p>Age of Youngest Driver</p>
    <select class="half" id="driver" name="">
      <option value="21-24">21-24</option>
      <option value="25+">25+</option>        
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="search" />
  <div class="fields" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="mitsub" />
  </div>    
</form>
```

Thanks and please help

Comment: Do you have a submit button?, show us how is the form send and what does return php

Comment: @SilverSurfer I update my question please check

Comment: Why you dont put name attr directly on html tags?

Comment: @NeerajMishra there is no option to select both, you said that some vehicles are available for both then how will it be possible? for that, you need to change select box to multiple and one more thing why you change the name of the select box like driverage and driver_age?

Comment: @SilverSurfer Because it have 2 names as driverage and driver_age

Comment: @Prateik From both i mean when users select 21-24 or 25+ then it picks the value from database and shows vehicles

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional statement inside your `foreach()` that adds `selected` attribute to `option`. This will ensure that the selected value is selected in the list of options.

```
<?php
if(count($vehicleType) > 0 ){
  foreach($vehicleType as $vt){
    echo "<option value='$vt'";
    if(isset($_GET['car_type']) && $_GET['car_type'] == $vt){
      echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">$vt</option>\r\n";
  }
}
?>
```

You can do this all in one, you just have to make sure the logic is correct.

```
echo "<option value='$vt'" . ((isset($_GET['car_type'] && $_GET['car_type'] == $vt) ? " selected" : "") . ">$vt</option>\r\n";
```

I just find it easier to work with a full `if` statement.

Comment: Actually it works fine for me only problem with age of driver field as for this field there are 2 columns in database that is driverage and driver_age.PLease also check screenshot of database ..http://prntscr.com/gldmh2

Comment: CHeck this one http://prntscr.com/gldncu this is when i select value 25+ and after click on search it works perfect but again when i click on search then it is like this http://prntscr.com/gldo6p